# How to ensure a list is blanked

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am using colab. I have a list with these values:

```
cents=[[5.4, 3.9, 1.3, 0.4], [5.8, 2.6, 4.0, 1.2], [7.7, 2.8, 6.7, 2.0]]
```

I established this list in my second block of code.

Now, further into my code, I want to clear this list and change the values to the average of values from another list. Here is my code for this:

```
cents=[]
def avg_and_assign(list_1, list_2, list_3):
 alc1=np.array(list_1)
 alc2=np.array(list_2)
 alc3=np.array(list_3)
 alc1_mean=np.mean(alc1, axis=0)
 alc2_mean=np.mean(alc2, axis=0)
 alc3_mean=np.mean(alc3, axis=0)
 alc1_mean1=alc1_mean[0:4]
 alc2_mean1=alc2_mean[0:4]
 alc3_mean1=alc3_mean[0:4]
 cent1=np.ndarray.tolist(alc1_mean1)
 cent2=np.ndarray.tolist(alc2_mean1)
 cent3=np.ndarray.tolist(alc3_mean1)
 cents.append(cent1)
 cents.append(cent2)
 cents.append(cent3)
cents=[cent1,cent2,cent3]
cent_array=np.array(cents)

print(cents)

avg_and_assign(avg_list_cent1, avg_list_cent2, avg_list_cent3)

print(cents)
```

Here are my outputs:

```
[[5.4, 3.9, 1.3, 0.4], [5.8, 2.6, 4.0, 1.2], [7.7, 2.8, 6.7, 2.0]]
[[5.4, 3.9, 1.3, 0.4], [5.8, 2.6, 4.0, 1.2], [7.7, 2.8, 6.7, 2.0], [5.005999999999999, 3.4180000000000006, 1.464, 0.2439999999999999], [5.971830985915493, 2.7845070422535207, 4.50281690140845, 1.4901408450704228], [6.972413793103449, 3.0862068965517238, 5.893103448275861, 2.1310344827586207]]
```

Why isn't my cents list becoming empty when I assign it empty? Can this only work in the same code block?

My function can append the average to the list, but I wanted cents to become a blank list first.

Thanks.

Comment: `cents` in that function is a local variable, unrelated to the global of the same name.  You should add `return cents` to the end of the function, then do `cents = avg_and_assign(...)`.

Comment: It seems that the indentation of the shown code doesn't match your real code. Better copy and paste it directly to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't Repeat Yourself ("DRY").  Use a loop to do your repetitive tasks.  Then, return the final list instead of trying to use globals.

```
def avg_and_assign(*lists):
    cents = []
    for lst in lists:
        alc = np.array(lst)
        alc_mean = np.mean(alc, axis=0)[:4]
        cents.append( np.ndarray.tolist(alc_mean) )
    return cents

cents=[cent1,cent2,cent3]
print(cents)

cents = avg_and_assign(avg_list_cent1, avg_list_cent2, avg_list_cent3)
print(cents)
```

It's not clear to me why you keep converting to and from numpy arrays.  In particular, why return a list of lists instead of a list of ndarrays?

Comment: Thanks! Honestly, I'm not sure either. I've only had intro to Python and this is my first real "here's some data and here's what I want you to do now get there" assignment. So I'm just trying all sorts of things. But I can't share my whole colab book and nor would I want to until I complete the assignment.

Also, I've never seen the *lists used in a function. What does that imply?

Comment: You ought to be able to figure that out from the context.  That takes all the parameters to the function and combines them into a single list.

Comment: Yes. That is what it seemed, I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Hi. So I'm running into issues later with my code since I changed it. I' running a while loop, and when I get to part in the while loop where it runs this function, I get an error that the list index is now out of range in another function. Do I need to change that to *lists as well?

Comment: You need to ask a new question.  We don't know what you have, and of course we can' see your other code.